# JavaMail API: NullPointerException When Accessing Outlook

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I'm currently using the following code to access my Outlook inbox.

```
public void readAllMsgsFromOutlook() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, MessagingException

{
    //String host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";

    String emailID = props.getEmail();
    String password = props.getPassword();
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");



    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", emailID, password);
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");

        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();

        System.out.println("Number of New Emails: " + msgs.length);


        for (int msgCounter = 0; msgCounter < msgs.length; msgCounter++) 

        {


            Message msg  = msgs[msgCounter];
            Address[] sender = msg.getFrom();
            Multipart mp =  (Multipart) msg.getContent(); // Throws null pointer exception 
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            Date sentdate = msg.getSentDate();
            String subject = msg.getSubject();
            String content = bp.getContent().toString();


            System.out.println("SENDER: " + sender);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE: " + sentdate.getDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT: " + subject);
            System.out.println("CONTENT: " + content);

        }


    } catch (Exception mex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

However I get a NullPointer exception using this code.

This is the result I get in console:

```
Number of New Emails: 2
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.set(ParameterList.java:561)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.parseParameters(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:404)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:224)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.parse(FetchResponse.java:158)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.<init>(FetchResponse.java:67)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:136)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:270)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.command(Protocol.java:313)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetch(IMAPProtocol.java:1529)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetch(IMAPProtocol.java:1521)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetchBodyStructure(IMAPProtocol.java:1221)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadBODYSTRUCTURE(IMAPMessage.java:1307)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getDataHandler(IMAPMessage.java:623)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1454)
    at JavaMailAPI.readAllMsgsFromOutlook(JavaMailAPI.java:65)
    at Main.main(Main.java:163)
```

I'm not sure why I get NullPointer exception if there are two emails in my inbox..?

Comment: I know what a nullpointer exception is I just don't see why I'm getting one in this specific case.

Comment: @thegauravmahawar In this case, the NullPointerException does not appear to be the result of passing or dereferencing null in the code.  It’s occurring internally in the mail provider.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of JavaMail classes from two different versions of JavaMail on your classpath.  Make sure you only have one jar file that includes the javax.mail.* classes.  If you're running in a Java EE application server that already includes JavaMail, make sure that you're not including any JavaMail classes in your application.